# Processing Network library freezing (no exceptions thrown)

Tags: java, networking, processing, tcp

So I did a little game of boat fights, working in a server/client fashion using Processing's Net's `Server` and `Client` class.

Everything works fine when I run both server and client on the same device (Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf), but the `Client`'s constructor freezes when trying to connect to the server running on Windows 10. Both client and server uses a class called `Connexion` :

```
Connexion{
  boolean isServer;
  Server s;
  Client c;

  Connexion(PApplet source, int port){ //To create a server
    isServer = true;
    s = new Server(source, port);
  }

  Connexion(PApplet source, int port, String ip){ //To create a client
    isServer = false;
    c = new Client(source, ip, port);
  }

  void update(){/*Dealing with messages ...*/}
}
```

What I did was exporting it then launching it twice, one as a server and one as a client. Using `127.0.0.1` as IP, they both work fine and I did all the game.

I just tried to get it to work on different devices, running as a Server on a Windows 10 and as a client on my Ubuntu. The server code runs fine, and no errors nor freezing happen during initialization. However, when the client tries to connect, the line `c = new Client(...)` pauses : no exceptions thrown, no messages in the console, ... nothing (I used `println()`s to know where it stopped). (The IP used was the one provided by `Server.ip()` on the server's side, 192.168.[...])

I guess it is either a firewall issue (McAffee asked for permition to access the internet, which I agreed to), or a Windows blocking something ? No clue. The [Processing Net documentation (Client class)](https://processing.org:8443/reference/libraries/net/Client.html) says

> If anything goes wrong with the connection, for example the host is not there or is listening on a different port, an exception is thrown.

When I tried to do the opposite (server as Ubuntu and client as Windows), `Server.ip()` gave 127.0.1.1 and nothing happenned but I suspect this to be the wrong IP anyway. Saddly I didn't had time to test anything else.

So my question is, **How can I make this work ?** and if there's no way to make it work without touching the system settings, how does multiplayer games manage it ? (all along the port used was 6666, I doubt it comes from there but I'll write it just in case).

Comment: Are you sure you can access the server machine from the client machine? Double check using a browser or the curl command.

Comment: I'm really new to networking ... I'll check what the 'curl' command is in the next days ...